# Got Download Traffic While Uploading With High Speed

Tags: centos, networking, backup, ftp, upload

When I upload my backup using ftp to my backup server, my upload speed get to `1.5Gb/s` which is good!
**BUT** I see strange things on download traffic!!
When my upload speed get bigger than `1Gb/s` I see download traffic upto `10Mb/s`.
I don't know whats really going on here!?
there is no app which cause this download traffic and they start together when ftp start tranfering!
I use `nload` to see traffic
Any explanation?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! To help you out we need more information about your connection type and bandwidth (upstream and downstream). How are you generating the downstream traffic? Please edit you question to add these details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chances are that the unexpected inbound traffic is simply acknowledgements of the data you're uploading. Assuming it's TCP/IP rather than UDP, of course. I would have thought 100:1 a little strong, but it is quite plausible.

Best thing might be to run something like `ntop` to see whether the incoming traffic addresses match the outbound traffic.

Comment: Thanks. I checked it and download traffic is comes from the same ip as upload goes.